Why isn't the sdkmanager distributed with correct directory structure?
I know this is not really a good question for SO, but I see no other outlet for this than the android-sdk-manager tag here. If you know of a better place to post this, please let me know with a comment, and I can remove the question.
In the sdkmanager install docs, it tells users to:


Download the latest "command line tools only" package from the Android Studio downloads page and unzip the package.
Move the unzipped cmdline-tools directory into a new directory of your choice, such as android_sdk. This new directory is your Android
SDK directory.
In the unzipped cmdline-tools directory, create a sub-directory called latest.
Move the original cmdline-tools directory contents, including the lib directory, bin directory, NOTICE.txt file, and source.properties
file, into the newly created latest directory. You can now use the
command-line tools from this location.


I see a bunch of other questions on here related to wrong environment variables, missing references to sdkmanager, etc. It seems like a lot of the confusion could be removed if the command line tools only packages were distributed as a zip file, that once unziped would already be in the correct directory structure, e.g. ~/android_sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/{bin, lib, NOTICE.txt, source.properties}
Is there some reason why this is not already distributed like this? And maybe a simple install script for setting the ANDROID_HOME variable?
Edit
I added a script here to essentially do this after the fact, if anyone is interested in helping develop it to be more generalized, but I still feel this is a hacky workaround rather than the ease of just distributing it correctly in the first place.
